# How can I include Tailwind CSS as external source in a Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, user-experience

The recommended way of directly including Tailwind CSS according to their documentation is to add

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

to the HTML *head*. But when I open a stack snippet and try to insert this URL `https://cdn.tailwindcss.com` as external library, it says:

[image]

Is there a way to add external libraries that don't end with `.css` or `.js`?

Comment: The extension is used to determine whether to insert a `script` or `style` tag, you could probably append `#.js` of `#.css` if you really wanted to use that input.

Comment: I see, wasn't obvious for me. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that it's possible to skip using the *Add an external library* button and directly insert the script tag in the HTML section:

[image]

That way, any library can be added. But it wasn't clear for me at first sight that this was possible.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear to me, why the *Add an external library* button only allows for `.js` and `.css` URLs, when you can literally paste every URL with the script tag in the HTML section itself.

Comment: The extension is used to determine whether to insert a `script` or `style` tag, you could probably append `#.js` of `#.css` if you really wanted to use that input, @andreas.

Comment: I'd consider this a slight bug. While unusual, it's not unheard of for external resources to have a file extension in the path that doesn't match the MIME type of what's being served. Better for the snippet interface to display a *warning* (*"Are you sure this is what you want? It may not work"*) than to forbid it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working Tailwind snippet:

```css
.as-console-wrapper{display:none!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>
<script>
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        clifford: "#da373d",
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>

<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-clifford">
  Hello world!
</h1>
```

See Tailwind's [Play CDN page](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) for more information.